# Let $m$ be the number of solutions of the equation $x^2 = 1$ in the ring $Z_n$, where $Φ_n$ is Euler group, $n> 2$.

Tags: group-theory, number-theory, elementary-number-theory

Let $m$ be the number of solutions of the equation $x^2 = 1$ in the ring $Z_n$, where  $Φ_n$ is Euler group, $n> 2$.

- Prove that $m$ is an even number.

Could anyone help me or give me a hint?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Prove that the set of solutions can be naturally grouped into pairs in a certain way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not clear to me why the question mentions $U(n)$ (I'm assuming by Euler group you mean group of units modulo $n$).

To see that the number of solutions to $x^2 = 1$ in $\mathbb  Z_n$ is even if $n>2$ note that if $x^2 = 1$ then also $(-x)^2 = 1$ and $x \neq -x$ hence solutions to the equation occur in pairs.

Hope this helps.